# Translation for form_tag submit button

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In Rails, when you have a form like this:

```
<% form_for @post do |f| %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

You can have a specific translation like this for when the button is clicked:

```
en:
  helpers:
    submit:
      create: "Create a {{model}}"
      update: "Confirm changes to {{model}}"
```

But I have a form_tag, which submits a GET to an index path to set a filter:

```
= form_tag admin_dashboard_index_path, method: :get, class: "table_filter" do
  = select_tag :company, options_for_select(@filter_companies.map{ |c| [c.name, c.id] }, params[:company]), include_blank: true, class: "selected"
  = submit_tag :submit, value: I18n.t('.general.filter'), class: 'btn'
```

How can I get a specific translation for this situation?

Comment: What do you mean exactly, you already have a `.general.filter` there, is that not working?

Comment: @Iceman The `.general.filter` is working as button label, but when you press the button that text becomes briefly `submit` and I want to change that text.

Comment: Hmm, that's strange. What is the generated html?

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="commit" value="Filter" class="btn" data-disable-with="submit">`

Comment: Try `= submit_tag :submit, value: I18n.t('.general.filter'), class: 'btn', data: { disable_with: t('.general.filter') }`

Comment: Yep that works, thanks! Can you add it as an answer, then I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to the method so that the button label stays the same after pressing it.

```
= submit_tag :submit, value: t('.general.filter'), class: 'btn', data: { disable_with: t('.general.filter') }
```

[submit_tag method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-submit_tag)